# ArgumentError after updating from Ruby 2.7 to Ruby 3.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify-app

After update ruby to 3.0.1 the very simple code fail to execute app_uninstalled_job.rb

```
class AppUninstalledJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform(shop_domain:, webhook:)
    shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: shop_domain)
```

with the error

```
Error performing AppUninstalledJob (Job ID: ***) from Async(default) in 0.18ms: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0; required keywords: shop_domain, webhook)):
.../app/jobs/app_uninstalled_job.rb:2:in `perform'
```

The data received correctly

```
Started POST "/webhooks/app_uninstalled" for 34.69.74.99 at 2021-07-20 04:44:31 +0000
Processing by ShopifyApp::WebhooksController#receive as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>876876876, "name"=>"shopname", "email"=>"***@gmail.com", "domain"=>"shop.myshopify.com", "province"=>.....}}
[ActiveJob] Enqueued AppUninstalledJob (Job ID: ) to Async(default) with arguments: {:shop_domain=>"shop.myshopify.com", :webhook=>{"id"=>876876876, "name"=>"shop", "email"=>"***@gmail.com", "domain"=>"shop.myshopify.com", "province"=>....}


[ActiveJob] [AppUninstalledJob] [****9] Performing AppUninstalledJob (Job ID: **99) from Async(default) enqueued at 2021-07-20T04:44:31Z with arguments: {:shop_domain=>"shop.myshopify.com", :webhook=>{"id"=>876876876, "name"=>"shop", "email"=>"***@gmail.com", "domain"=>"shop.myshopify.com", "province"....}
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 2327)
```

It is related to Handling argument delegation https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/

How to resolve the error ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0; required keywords: shop_domain, webhook)

UPDATE: code for webhook controller

```
module ShopifyApp
  class MissingWebhookJobError < StandardError; end

  class WebhooksController < ActionController::Base
    include ShopifyApp::WebhookVerification

    def receive
      params.permit!
      job_args = { shop_domain: shop_domain, webhook: webhook_params.to_h }
      webhook_job_klass.perform_later(job_args)
      head(:ok)
    end

    private

    def webhook_params
      params.except(:controller, :action, :type)
    end

    def webhook_job_klass
      webhook_job_klass_name.safe_constantize || raise(ShopifyApp::MissingWebhookJobError)
    end

    def webhook_job_klass_name(type = webhook_type)
      [webhook_namespace, "#{type}_job"].compact.join('/').classify
    end

    def webhook_type
      params[:type]
    end

    def webhook_namespace
      ShopifyApp.configuration.webhook_jobs_namespace
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you please add the code of this action: `ShopifyApp::WebhooksController#receive`?

Comment: @Deepesh code added, thank you for help

Comment: Could it be an "old" job (a job that you enqueued with the older ruby and was still living in your redis)? Does it happen with new jobs you try now?

Comment: The solution is in your question itself (the link), add double splat operator: `webhook_job_klass.perform_later(**job_args)`

Comment: @Deepesh  kahan add kiya hai code? I still see the same in the `shopify_app` engine.  https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/blob/b0d29de4a30b60701c00b2b183cfb20e651e82ed/app/controllers/shopify_app/webhooks_controller.rb#L11

Comment: @SagarRanglani He has probably monkey patched the method.

Comment: Thanks! I added a PR: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/pull/1320

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have shared the link regarding the changes in Ruby 3, the answer is in the link itself:

> Separation of positional and keyword arguments in Ruby 3.0:

> In most cases, you can avoid incompatibility by adding the double splat operator. It explicitly specifies passing keyword arguments instead of a Hash object. Likewise, you may add braces {} to explicitly pass a Hash object, instead of keyword arguments.

Now looking at your code you are doing this:

```
job_args = { shop_domain: shop_domain, webhook: webhook_params.to_h }
webhook_job_klass.perform_later(job_args)
```

i.e., passing a hash to the method instead you intend to pass keyword arguments which you can fix by adding a double splat operator:

```
webhook_job_klass.perform_later(**job_args)
```

**More info on the error:**

The error is:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0; required keywords: shop_domain, webhook)):
```

which means `shop_domain` and `webhook` are required keyword arguments and you are passing a single argument as Ruby now treats the hash as a single argument instead of the keyword arguments until you add the double splat operator.